# How to pick a random element in an np array only if it isn't a certain value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm using `python`.

I have what might be an easy question, though I can't see it.

If I have an array `x = array([1.0,0.0,1.5,0.0,6.0])` and `y = array([1,2,3,4,5])`

I'm looking for an efficient way to pick randomly between `1.0`,`1.5`,`6.0` ignoring all zeros while retaining the index for comparison with another `array` such as `y`. So if I was to randomly pick `6.0` I could still relate it to `y[4]`.

The reason for the efficient bit is that eventually I want to pick between possibly 10 values from an array of 1000+ with the rest zero. Depending on how intensive the other calculations become depends on the size of the array though it could easily become much larger than 1000.

Thanks

Comment: Oddly enough, a very similar question was just asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440102/index-of-a-random-choice-from-numpy-array); you can use `.nonzero()` to get the indices of the nonzero elements and then choose one of those.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @DSM I'm not sure that's efficient in terms of either runtime or memory.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: if there are relatively few non-zero values, as the OP has (10 of 1000+) then you're going to have to find them to get decent performance, which is O(n).  You could avoid storing the indices (which if the matrix is sparse is going to be negligible storage anyway) by looping and drawing a new random number each time a nonzero value is spotted but that's going to be a lot slower.

Comment: Thanks guys I appreciate the help. I'll have a look through and post back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.nonzero()` will only skip the `0` s, for any value that you want to skip this is a solution:

```
In [281]:

x = np.array([1.0,0.0,1.5,0.0,6.0])
non_zero_idx=np.argwhere(x!=0).flatten()
np.random.shuffle(non_zero_idx)
random_pick=x[non_zero_idx]
random_pick[0]
Out[281]:
1.5
In [282]:

%%timeit

x = np.array([1.0,0.0,1.5,0.0,6.0])
non_zero_idx=np.argwhere(x!=0).flatten()
np.random.shuffle(non_zero_idx)
random_pick=x[non_zero_idx]
random_pick[0]
10000 loops, best of 3: 104 µs per loop
```

If you are just interested in getting one random pick (rather then an `array` of random picks) , `x[np.random.choice(non_zero_idx,1)]` will be just enough. But that is actually slower:

```
In [286]:

%%timeit

x = np.array([1.0,0.0,1.5,0.0,6.0])
non_zero_idx=np.argwhere(x!=0).flatten()
x[np.random.choice(non_zero_idx,1)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 173 µs per loop
```

There are three way to get random picks, as @AndyHayden pointed out, behaving differently different array sizes:

```
In [299]:

X=np.random.random(100000)
In [300]:

%timeit np.random.choice(X, 1)
%timeit X[np.random.randint(0,len(X),1)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 70.3 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.6 µs per loop
In [301]:

%%timeit
np.random.shuffle(X)
X[0]
10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop

In [302]:

X=np.random.random(10000)
In [303]:

%timeit np.random.choice(X, 1)
%timeit X[np.random.randint(0,len(X),1)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 70.1 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.6 µs per loop
In [304]:

%%timeit
np.random.shuffle(X)
X[0]
100 loops, best of 3: 12.6 ms per loop
```

Appears `X[np.random.randint(0,len(X),1)]` is the best.

Comment: It's may only slower for small examples.

Comment: Good point. The `shuffle` way would most likely to be the the best choice when we want an `array` to iterate though it.

Comment: Another trick is to use ravel rather than flatten (as this doesn't create a copy). (can't +1 again, but thanks for the additional timings! :) )

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to accept probabilistic times and you have fewer than 50% ignored values, you can just retry until you have an acceptable value.

If you can't, you're going to have to go over the entire array at least once to know which values to ignore, but that takes n memory.